# IPv6 replacement for ICMP timestamp

Tags: ipv6, icmp, icmpv6

Does any standard IPv6 protocol has anything analogous to an ICMP timestamp message?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can read in the ICMP codes, there is no equivalent within ipv6. Below you can find [a table](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.halu101/icmp.htm) showing all possible ICMPv6 codes.
[image]